# aggregating model summaries from list of models

Tags: r, list, apply, plyr, sapply

I am running same models several times on different subset of data, for example,

```
  data("mtcars")
  head("mtcars")

  table(mtcars$cyl, useNA = "ifany")
```

I am fitting the model `(mpg ~ hp + wt)` for each cylinder type.

```
 foo <- mtcars %>%
          group_by(cyl) %>%
             nest() %>%
               mutate(model= map(data, rms::ols(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = .)))
```

When I try this

```
  foo %>%
    {map(.$model, summary)}
```

I get the model summary from all three models but this does not include the estimates for intercept.

I am not interested in fitting the model using `lm` function, I am specifically interested in solutions involving fitting `rms::ols()` function.

Any help on aggregating the summaries from multiple models using `rms::ols()` and that includes estimates for intercept, will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your code works correctly, i.e. creates the models. What you don't like is that the summary function for rms models (`rms:::summary.rms`) doesn't print information about the intercept, is that it? If it is, I think you should re-write your question. The part about the mapping doesn't seem to matter too much, you just want a custom summary function

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro, yes that is correct Ricardo, the rms summary function is not printing the estimates for intercept. However if we see the induvidual model summary, `foo$model` the intercepts are printed, but I am not sure how to put them all together in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your question is more about having a custom summary function.

Note that what you called "induvidual model summary, `foo$model`" is not a summary (as in output for a summary function), is just the default printing method of a `rms` object.

You can use `summary.lm()`:

```
foo %>%
  {map(.$model, summary.lm)}
```

Extra: if you don't want your models saved as a tibble, you can use `group_split` -> `map`, instead of `group_by` -> `nest` -> `map`:

```
foo <- mtcars %>%
  group_split(cyl) %>%
  map(~ rms::ols(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = .x))
```

Now, `foo` is a list and you can do more naturally:

```
map(foo, summary.lm)
```